# how ping a PC by another switch's console use secureCRT in rstp

Tags: ieee-802.1w

In secureCRT SWC's console ping PCA in **rstp demo** in the pic?

It's a loop Topology and on each switch I set stp mode rstp and every ports are bind default **vlan1**.

I open the switchC's loopback 0 and my console can ping success

But can't ping to pcA . (I have close the pc firewall)

Waiting for your good answer.Thank you!

**the topology**:
[image]
**SWA**:

*dis stp root*

mstid: 0,root bridge id:32768.70ba-ef6e-356a,extpathcost: 20,intpathcost:0
root port: g1/0/24.

*dis stp brief*

port g1/0/23,role designate,stp state forwarding.
port g1/0/24,role root,stp state forwarding.

**SWB**:

*dis stp root*

mstid: 0,root bridge id:32768.70ba-ef6e-356a,extpathcost: 20,intpathcost:0
root port: g1/0/23.

*dis stp brief*

port g1/0/1,role designate,stp state forwarding.
port g1/0/22,role alte,stp state discarding.
port g1/0/23,role root,stp state forwarding.
port g1/0/24,role alternate,stp state discarding.

**SWC(root bridge)**:

*dis stp root*

mstid: 0,root bridge id:32768.70ba-ef6e-356a,extpathcost: 0,intpathcost:0
root port: null.

*dis stp brief*

port g1/0/22,role designate,stp state forwarding.
port g1/0/23,role designate,stp state forwarding.
port g1/0/24,role designate,stp state forwarding.

**SWD**:

*dis stp root*

mstid: 0,root bridge id:32768.70ba-ef6e-356a,extpathcost: 20,intpathcost:0
root port: g1/0/24.

*dis stp brief*

port g1/0/23,role designate,stp state forwarding.
port g1/0/24,role root,stp state forwarding.

Comment: You aren't providing enough information. What are the switch configurations? You should edit your question to provide all the relevant information.

Comment: hello, i'm a newbie.I only set the swb's loopback ip for test and all of switchs set rstp mode.that's all.and of couse every ports is default to join vlan1

Comment: Switches don't have loopbacks, unless they are layer-3 switches. They can have management interfaces if they are managed switches. You don't even include the switch model. Without things like the configurations and interface status, we are just guessing what you did wrong. That means you will only be able to get opinion-based answers, which are off-topic here.

Comment: because i use the H3C s5120 serial.it's a layer-3 device.every ports only use vlan1 by default.and every switch only set rstp like swa.it's a rstp demo so....

Comment: It sounds like you want an answer, but you will find that you aren't going to get one unless you provide all the information. You need to edit your question to include everything. What do the switches say about the STP status? What are the configurations? What is the status of the ports? Nobody can answer your question without having the necessary information.

Comment: thank you for your advice.tomorrow i will add these information

Comment: Generally speaking, the loopback is a separate interface from VLAN interfaces.  Instead of a loopback, create a VLAN interface and give that an IP address.

Comment: the vlan interface and loopback must the same principle.but is it the problem because the console have no ip address.though it can ping to local switch loopback.but it can't connect to another switch's ip.

Comment: You have to configure an address on the vlan interface like this:  <Switch> system-view
[Switch] interface vlan-interface 1
[Switch-Vlan-interface1] ip address 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0

Answer (score 0):

Ping is a layer3 verification tool.  It seems your main concern is your layer2 topology / configuration.

In any case, each switch needs to have a default gateway configured if pings are to work across different IP subnets.  If all switch management IP addresses are on the same LAN/VLAN/subnet then pings should work without having a default gateway configured.

So, what are you management IP addresses on each switch?  If they are all 2.2.2.x than ping will work, provided your layer 2 configuration is valid.

Lastly, that direct link between SWB and SWC really complicates the topology and what does it really give you?  There is already a redundant path between them.

My recommendation is to home run each switch to SWB and minimize STP.  Get another SWB-B stacked and to dual runs to each IDF switch.  Something like below:

[image]